# CSS Dropdown menu alignment between menu and submenu

Tags: css, menu, position, alignment, submenu

I'm having a lot of problems how to align menu and submenu. My submenu appears on next menu item. 
Here's the code:

HTML

```
<div class="drsalnik">
<ul class="navbar">

<li><a href="Stranzaindexom.html" ><div class="item">Domov</div></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="Stranzaindexom.html" >Novice</a></li>
<li><a href="1stran-podstran1.html" >Akcije & popusti</a></li>
<li><a href="1stran-podstran2.html" >Najbolj iskano</a></li>
<li><a href="1stran-podstran3.html" >Fotografije tedna</a></li>
<li><a href="1stran-podstran4.html" >Foto-zgodbe</a></li>
<li><a href="1stran-podstran5.html" >Dostava</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="2stran.html" ><div class="item">Fotoaparati</div></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="2stran-podstran1.html" >DSLR</a></li>
<li><a href="2stran-podstran2.html" >Kompaktni</a></li>
<li><a href="2stran-podstran3.html" >Analogni</a></li>
<li><a href="2stran-podstran4.html" >Video kamere</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<ul><a href="3stran.html" ><div class="item three">Objektivi</div></a></ul>
<ul><a href="4stran.html" ><div class="item four">Stojala</div></a></ul>
<ul><a href="5stran.html" ><div class="item five">Filtri in bliskavice</div></a></ul>

<ul><a href="6stran.html" ><div class="item six">Ostala oprema</div></a></ul>

</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.drsalnik {
width:100%;
margin:  auto;
overflow:hidden;
border: 0;
background-color: white;
}

.item {
  height:40px;
  width:16.5%;
  float:left;
  background-position: left top;
  transition:width 0.5s ease;
  font-size: 140%;
  text-align: center;
 border: black solid .5px;
 opacity: 0.8;
}

.drsalnik:hover .item {
  width:16.5%;
  transition:width 0.5s ease;
   opacity: 0.4;
}

.drsalnik .item:hover{
    width:17.5%;
    transition:width 0.5s ease;
    background-position: center;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 5;
}

.navbar{
    list-style: none;
}

.navbar li{
    display: block;
}

.navbar ul li{
    opacity: 0.6;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.navbar li:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
}

.navbar li:hover .item{
    opacity: 1;
}

.navbar li ul{
    display: none;
    font-size: 110%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    padding:10px;
    font-style: italic;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar li:hover ul{
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    width: 14.5%;
}
```

So the idea is to make submenu of first menu item appears right under and not at the next menu item. I try to change displays and positions almost everywhere, but none seems to work.

Here's jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2mp6ajdx/

Comment: Check out this link: http://code-tricks.com/simple-css-drop-down-menu/.. Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to add margin-left: -16.5% to .navbar li ul

```
.navbar li ul{
    display: none;
    font-size: 110%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    padding:10px;
    font-style: italic;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -16.5%;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.