# Gap between menu and submenu on hover with after

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menuitem, elementor

I have a wordpress site with **elementor** and **elementskit** for `megamenu`.
I am trying to add `::after` to `<a>` tag to gap between **menu-item** and **sub-menu** but something is wrong and `after` doesn't appear in source code,
Hence gap prevents mouse moving from `menu-item` to `sub-menu`.

```
<ul id="menu-new-main" class="elementskit-navbar-nav elementskit-menu-po-left submenu-click-on">
<li id="menu-item-18011" class="menu-item-after menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-18011 nav-item elementskit-dropdown-has relative_position elementskit-dropdown-menu-default_width elementskit-mobile-builder-content" data-vertical-menu="750px">
    <a href="#/" class="ekit-menu-nav-link ekit-menu-dropdown-toggle">אודות</a>
    <ul class="elementskit-dropdown elementskit-submenu-panel">
        <li id="menu-item-18013" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18013 nav-item elementskit-mobile-builder-content" data-vertical-menu="750px">
            <a href="https://link" class=" dropdown-item">Our Team</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-18014" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18014 nav-item elementskit-mobile-builder-content" data-vertical-menu="750px">
            <a href="https://link" class=" dropdown-item">Our Achievments</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-18022" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18022 nav-item elementskit-mobile-builder-content" data-vertical-menu="750px">
            <a href="https://link" class=" dropdown-item">Vision</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I tried adding any of these options still no `after`.

```
#menu-new-main >li >a::after{
    display: block;
height:20px;
width:100%;
}

.menu-item-has-children  > a::after {
    display: block;
height:20px;
width:100%;
}


.menu-item-after > a::after {
    display: block;
height:20px;
width:100%;
}
```

Can anyone direct me to a solution??
Live site is [here](https://new.zalul.org.il/).

I looked at many solutions here but none did the job.
[CSS Dropdown menu alignment between menu and submenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25338586/css-dropdown-menu-alignment-between-menu-and-submenu)
[Gap Between dropdown menu and sub menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40174749/gap-between-dropdown-menu-and-sub-menu)
[Hover submenu doesn't stay opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55863030/hover-submenu-doesnt-stay-opened)

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the `content` property if you want the `::after` pseudo-element to work as block-level-element.

```css
.menu-item-after>a::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-new-main" class="elementskit-navbar-nav elementskit-menu-po-left submenu-click-on">
  <li id="menu-item-18011" class="menu-item-after menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-18011 nav-item elementskit-dropdown-has relative_position elementskit-dropdown-menu-default_width elementskit-mobile-builder-content"
    data-vertical-menu="750px">
    <a href="#/" class="ekit-menu-nav-link ekit-menu-dropdown-toggle">אודות</a>
    <ul class="elementskit-dropdown elementskit-submenu-panel">
      <li id="menu-item-18013" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18013 nav-item elementskit-mobile-builder-content" data-vertical-menu="750px">
        <a href="https://link" class=" dropdown-item">Our Team</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-18014" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18014 nav-item elementskit-mobile-builder-content" data-vertical-menu="750px">
        <a href="https://link" class=" dropdown-item">Our Achievments</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-18022" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18022 nav-item elementskit-mobile-builder-content" data-vertical-menu="750px">
        <a href="https://link" class=" dropdown-item">Vision</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. Just added `content: "";` still on mouse exit hover state sub-menu disappears. I made height of `after` even bigger but in vain.

Comment: It seems that `after` is situated to the left on the menu item and not under as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it so:

```
.elementskit-dropdown-has > a::after, .menu-item-has-children > a::after {
    content: "";
    display: flex;
    height: 52px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 72%;
}
```